# My ros topic can't echo any info

Tags: move-base, topic, rqt, message

My code of node is following

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
//modbus库头文件
#include "modbus/modbus-rtu.h"
//向量头文件
#include "vector"
#include "string"
//电机目标转速消息头文件
#include "fox_msgs/car_cmd.h"
//底层控制器反馈消息头文件
#include "fox_msgs/car_data.h"

//速度寄存器地址
#define READ_SPEED 0
//电压寄存器地址
#define READ_POWER_VOLTAGE  16
//陀螺仪寄存器地址
#define READ_MPU  17


using namespace std;

uint16_t mbbuf[35];
uint16_t probeen=0;
//实例化底盘消息
fox_msgs::car_data  my_data;
modbus_t *mb=NULL;

void translate_mb_data(void)
{
    //共用体
    union {
        double dd;
        uint16_t id[4];
    } d_to_uint;
    //各个轮子转速
    uint16_t *mbp=&mbbuf[READ_SPEED];
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        d_to_uint.id[3]=*mbp++;
        d_to_uint.id[2]=*mbp++;
        d_to_uint.id[1]=*mbp++;
        d_to_uint.id[0]=*mbp++;
        my_data.speed[i]=d_to_uint.dd;
    }
    //读取电压
    my_data.power_voltage=mbbuf[READ_POWER_VOLTAGE];
    //IMU
    mbp=&mbbuf[READ_MPU];
    union {
        float fd;
        uint16_t id[2];
    } f_to_uint;
    for(int i=0; i<9; i++) {
        f_to_uint.id[1]=*mbp++;
        f_to_uint.id[0]=*mbp++;
        my_data.mpu[i]=f_to_uint.fd;
    }
}
//car_cmd消息回调函数
void twistCallback(const fox_msgs::car_cmd & mycmd)
{
    if(mycmd.speed.size()!=4) return;
    union {
        double dd;
        uint16_t id[4];
    } d_to_uint;
    uint16_t send_data[17];
    uint16_t *p=send_data;
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        d_to_uint.dd=mycmd.speed[i];
        *p++=d_to_uint.id[3];
        *p++=d_to_uint.id[2];
        *p++=d_to_uint.id[1];
        *p++=d_to_uint.id[0];
    }
    if(mycmd.been!=probeen)  send_data[16]=mycmd.been;
    else send_data[16]=0;
    probeen=mycmd.been;
    //写入寄存器
    int res = modbus_write_registers(mb,0,17,send_data);
    //std::cout << "res: " << res << std::endl;
}
std::string serial_port="/dev/ttyS";
std::string usbserial_port="/dev/ttyUSB";
std::string connection_port = "";
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    //实例化一个string的向量
    std::vector<std::string> port;
    port.push_back(serial_port);
    port.push_back(usbserial_port);
    ROS_INFO("scaning available port");
    //连接标志位
    bool is_connected = false;

    for(int j=0; j<port.size(); j++) {
        for(int i=0; i < 127; i++) {
            std::string curr_port = port[j] + std::to_string(i);
            //连接串口 curr_port.c_str() 波特率为115200
            if(!(mb=modbus_new_rtu(curr_port.c_str(),115200,'N',8,1))) continue;
            //设置从机地址为1如果返回-1则为失败
            if(modbus_set_slave(mb,1)==-1) {
                modbus_free(mb);
                continue;
            }
            if(modbus_connect(mb)==-1) {
                modbus_free(mb);
                continue;
            }
            modbus_set_response_timeout(mb,0,200000);
            if(modbus_read_input_registers(mb,0,35,mbbuf)==35) {
                connection_port = curr_port;
                is_connected = true;
                break;
            }
        }//end for
        //如果连接成功跳出循环
        if(is_connected) break;
        continue;
    }//end for
    //判断是否连接成功
    if(!is_connected) {
        ROS_ERROR_STREAM("control borad connection failed");
        return -1;
    }
    ROS_INFO_STREAM("available prot: " << connection_port);
    modbus_set_response_timeout(mb,0,200000);

    //设置速度消息长度4,imu消息长度9
    my_data.speed.resize(4);
    my_data.mpu.resize(9);

    //初始化节点
    ros::init(argc, argv, "car_controller");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    //创建发布者car_data
    ros::Publisher car_data_pub = nh.advertise<fox_msgs::car_data>("car_data", 10);
    //创建订阅者car_cmd
    ros::Subscriber car_control_sub=nh.subscribe("car_cmd",10,twistCallback);
    //20hz
    ros::Rate loop_rate(20);
    while (ros::ok()) {
        //动态内存分配
        memset(mbbuf,0,35*2);
        usleep(2*1000);
        //请求modbus
        if(modbus_read_input_registers(mb,0,35,mbbuf)==35) {
            translate_mb_data();
            //发布car_data
            car_data_pub.publish(my_data);
        }
        ros::spinOnce();
        loop_rate.sleep();
    }
    modbus_close(mb);
    modbus_free(mb);
    return 0;
}
```

And I run `rostopic echo /car_cmd` and use rqt to sent message.[image]

But it didn't echo any message.
Following is the topic info

```
rostopic info /car_cmd
Type: fox_msgs/car_cmd

Publishers: 
 * /fox_kinematics (http://192.168.1.49:45657/)
 * /rqt_gui_py_node_19849 (http://192.168.1.49:32923/)

Subscribers: 
 * /fox_base (http://192.168.1.49:43589/)
 * /rostopic_19951_1701253751080 (http://192.168.1.49:41793/)
```

And runing rostopic hz /car_cmd and it shows that

```
average rate: 10.001
    min: 0.089s max: 0.105s std dev: 0.00083s window: 1514
```

I also use  `rostopic pub /car_cmd fox_msgs/car_cmd "{speed:2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0],been: 0}"` ,but still not echo corrently

Comment: Running the rostopic hz and it shows that "average rate: 10.001
 min: 0.089s max: 0.105s std dev: 0.00083s window: 1514
"I don't know why

Comment: What debug steps have you taken here? Have you demonstrated that you actually are getting to the line of code that does the publishing?